# Could anyone explain these kinds of transactions on paypal?

Tags: scams, fraud, paypal, transaction, financial-statements

From the following transaction history, we could see that Despiau Bruno (Probably fake name) added 229.22 USD to my paypal account. Then he, without my knowledge, use it to buy 225x Kaspersky Internet Security at $1 per unit (which is fake shell site as from the per unit price) using my paypal balance. Then he tries? to remove another 225 USD from my balance but was put on hold. He was able to resume the account and complete the transaction. The rest is pretty confusing to me as he tried to deposit another 218.30 USD into my account and dispute it back for a refund. In the end my account was negative but, I was able to return it to 0.00 USD by 20 March.

[image: Anonymized view of paypal transaction history]

I want to know if anybody had experienced about this scheme before me and how to prevent it from happening. Any further analysis of money flow is also appreciated.

Comment: "and how to prevent it from happening".  Change  your password?  Scan your computer and smartphone for viruses?

Comment: ^ this. Buy some of that kaspersky internet security !